# Java SOAP/JAX-WS: How to set timeouts?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am calling a webservice with Java. It is working well but I'd like to set a connection timeout too.

My code:

```
URL urlwsdl = new URL ("file://" + wsdl);
QName qn = new QName("http://myserver/myservice", "MyService");
port = new TimeSeriesService_Service (urlwsdl, qn).getMyServicePort (); 

BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
prov.getRequestContext ().put (BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://server1/myservice");
prov.getRequestContext ().put (BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "max");
prov.getRequestContext ().put (BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "secret");

QueryRequest1 req = new QueryRequest1 ();
QueryResponse1 res = port.queryRequest1 (req);  // *** TIMEOUT for ~2 minutes
```

I found some posts on the internet. They use the context of the binding provider as I do for http-auth.

e.g.

```
prov.getRequestContext ().put ("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 1000000);
```

But they use objects I do not have in my namespace.

e.g.

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout
com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout
```

I have sun.net but not .client.
I have com.sun.xml but not .ws.

I have a simple java jdk (1.7, Debian 8.3, 64bit) and can compile and run my webservice, the webclient and also wsimport. No netbeans and no jboss installed.

Any ideas how I can set a timeout?
Thanks for help!
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the JDK JAX-WS implementation you probably should set the internal properties

```
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", timeout);
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", timeout);
```

Please upvote my JIRA issue to standardize this in an upcoming version of JAX-WS 
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1166

Comment: I have com.sun.xml.internal.ws but then no connect.
Do I need a external JAR beside the JDK?

Comment: No everything you need is in the JDK. Check the class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties` to see i you have the exact same values.

Comment: I get this error: The type JAXWSProperties is not accessible due to restriction on required library /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar

Comment: You should always avoid using classes in `com.sun` package. My suggestion was only that you look at the constant field defined in your JDK. Then you should copy it in your code.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have any other JAX-WS runtime in your classpath eg CXF, glassfish or others. They will override the one in the JDK.

Comment: thank you! I missunderstood it. I thought about constants and not about constant-values. its working now!

Comment: The page pointed by @Willem Salembier was moved here https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/issues/1166

Comment: I am using SpringBoot with apache cxf and it works using `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout`

Comment: What is the unit of time in timeout? Miliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

And here is one more. None of the options mentioned here or in related posts worked for me. Really, what a mess...

```
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 3000);
```